# ROR : Workflow gem : I want to implement dynamic states from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, workflow, metaprogramming

I am currrently working on a project that has to implement dynamic workflow.

> **Dynamic**: I store workflow's states in database table called **wf_steps** and the workflow gem has to create `states` for a particular workflow  from the database

For that I am trying to use the [workflow gem](https://github.com/geekq/workflow). You can see how it initializes states and corresponding events in the gem's github-page.

My code:

```
class SpsWorkflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :wf_steps
  include Workflow
  workflow do
    # binding.pry
    # read wf-states from the database
    # for now let event be same for all the states
    self.wf_steps.each do |step|
      state step.title.to_sym do
        event :assign, transitions_to: :assigning
        event :hire, transitions_to: :hiring
        event :not_hire, transitions_to: :not_hiring
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Expectation and Problem encountered:**

I expected in the code block below the term `self.wf_steps` would return my `SpsWorkflow`'s instance/collection. However the `self` keyword returns `#<Workflow::Specification:0x000000063e23e8 @meta={}, @states={}>` when I use `binding.pry` inside the `workflow` method's block ( I commented in the code )

```
# read wf-states from the database
# for now let event be same for all the states
  self.wf_steps.each do |step|
    state step.title.to_sym do
```

Need you help, thanks

EDIT:
I also tried storing the instance in a variable and using the variable inside the block passing to the `workflow` method call.

```
class SpsWorkflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow
  sps_instance = self
```

But I got the instance of the class `SpsWorkflow` like

```
SpsWorkflow(id: integer, workflow_state: string, assigned_to: integer, title: string, description: string, organization_id: integer, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

but I want

```
 #<SpsWorkflow id: 1, workflow_state: "step1", assigned_to: nil, title: "Software Engineer", description: "Hire best engineer", organization_id: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-08-08 00:58:12", updated_at: "2015-08-08 00:58:12">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it using a activerecord callback

```
class SpsWorkflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow
  after_initialize do
    sps_instance = self
    SpsWorkflow.workflow do
      # read wf-states as well as events from the database
      sps_instance.wf_steps.each do |step|
        state step.title.to_sym do
          event :assign, transitions_to: :step2
          event :hire, transitions_to: :hire
          event :not_hire, transitions_to: :not_hiring
        end
      end
    end
  end
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :wf_steps
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used:

```
workflow do
  self.something
end
```

`self` in the context of this block will refer to the `WorkflowSpecification`. If you really want access to the instance of `SpsWorkflow`, you may have to pass it into the block or assign it to a different variable and use it there.

Comment: thanks, I tried to pass the current instance using variable `current_instance = self` but it stored the instance of the class like ` SpsWorkflow(id: integer, workflow_state: string, assigned_to: integer, title: string, description: string, organization_id: integer, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)` but I needed the instance of the `#<SpsWorkflow id: 1, workfl....`